# Error in Compiling TensorFlow1.15 no such package '@local_config_git//'

Tags: tensorflow, compilation, bazel

In my try to install TensorFlow(1.15) by Source Compiling using bazel (0.26.1) got this error:

```
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/core:version_info_gen' failed; build aborted: no such package '@local_config_git//': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/odroid/buildFile/tensorflow/tensorflow-1.15.3/third_party/git/git_configure.bzl",
```

How I can fix it? and Where is url for this package?

Comment: I don't know much about `git` and nothing about using it as a build tool, but when I see `@local_config_git//`, I think that is possibly generated by something like `@local_config_git/$HOME_UNSET_VAR/`. If not, then I have no idea.

Comment: My guess would be that you don't have git installed. @local_config_git// is syntax for a bazel repository name local_config_git and as its missing I assume it failed to find the git binary or something about running it failed. Without more of the build logs we can't help with any more than that.

Comment: were you able to solve this

Comment: @LakshayAwasthi yes, i downloaded packages manually.